# ST_Project all points in a table

Tags: postgis

I have an SQL table containing ID, longitude and latitude (WGS84) of several points. I would like to add a new column containing the new latitude of every point projected 5Km north.

I see that PostGIS offers the tool [ST_Project](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Project.html), which appears to do exactly what I would like to do. The issue is that I am not familiar with its syntax. I don't know how to apply `ST_Project` to all the points at the same time and how to add its output to a new column in the original table.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Note that coding questions are expected to contain code. It's a lot easier to understand where you're headed if we see what you've got, and the answer can be in the context of the tables as named.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to insert the results into a new column you first need to alter your table to have this new column. Presuming you wish to store the new latitude value as numeric to four decimal places:

```
ALTER TABLE original_table ADD COLUMN new_lat numeric(6,4);
```

You then need to perform an update query to update your new column:

```
UPDATE TABLE original_table
SET new_lat = ST_Y(ST_Project(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(' || lon || ' ' || lat || ')'),5000,0)::geometry);
```

First of all `UPDATE TABLE original_table SET new_lat =...` is telling PostgreSQL that I want to update the value in `new_lat` with the result of the following query on a per-row basis.

In the subsequent query, starting from the innermost function, I've first created a geography object using `ST_GeogFromText` and supplying a WKT which is constructed using the longitude and latitude values. This geography is passed into the ST_Project function along with vales for the second and third arguments which are distance and azimuth respectively. In the documentation under Synopsis you'll see:

> geography ST_Project(geography g1, float distance, float azimuth);

This is saying that the function will return a Geography object and that it expects three arguments: a geography (g1), followed by a distance in meters (distance) and an azimuth in radians (azimuth).

The ST_Project function returns the new geography point object so the final step is to return its latitude, or Y, coordinate using [ST_Y](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html).

---

**Update:** As per @Ray's comment, the ST_Y function requires a geometry so a cast must be included prior to calling the function. Updated above.

Comment: Thank you, that was extremely clear and helpful. I found that `ST_Y` supports only geometry and not geography, so I changed your code to `UPDATE original_table SET new_lat = ST_Y(ST_Project(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(' || lon || ' ' || lat || ')'),5000,0)::geometry);` and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Ray Ah yes, missed that step! Glad it helped anyway.